# Работа в консоли с PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Создал роль, не могу зайти в нее и создать бд. В чем может быть проблема?

```
PS C:\Users\User\project> psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:<ввожу пароль>
psql (11.1)
WARNING: Console code page (866) differs from Windows code page (1251)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE ROLE admin WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'Rt47';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# ALTER ROLE admin CREATEDB;
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q
PS C:\Users\User\project> psql -U Admin
Password for user Admin:<ввожу пароль>
psql: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "Admin" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь `admin` и пользователь `Admin` - это два разных пользователя. Поэтому вполне логично, что вы не можете авторизоваться под несуществующим пользователем. Сообщение об ошибке об этом не говорит намеренно из соображений безопасности.